# Powershell: How to unlock bitlocker encrypted drive simple way?

Tags: powershell, bitlocker

Is it possible to unlock a bitlocker encrypted drive in a simple way?

In the command line I would use something like:

```
manage-bde -unlock -pw d:
```

and next type the password. But for powershell the best I got so far is something like this:

```
Unlock-Bitlocker -MountPoint x: -Password (ConvertTo-Securestring "MyPassword" -AsPlainText -Force)
```

I don't want to convert my password to secure string I just want to type it manually, I know mange-bde also works on powershell but I was wondering if there is a powershell way to do this the simple way?

Comment: Have you tried Read-Host?

Comment: No, can you give an example on how I would use read-host to unlock an encrypted drive?

Comment: You use Read-Host then use ConvertTo-Securestring. If you want a prompt you’re going to need to use a PowerShell script. That’s how you will accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following powershell script to prompt for a password, type it in securely, and then run the rest of your script.

```
$UserCredential = Get-Credential -Message "Enter a password" -UserName "not applicable"

Unlock-Bitlocker -MountPoint x: -Password $UserCredential.Password
```

The result will look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I'm not planing on using a script, just a quick way to unlock a bitlocker drive.

Comment: You can run both lines one at the time in powershell or just use manage-bde. There's no real advantage in going a full professional powershell route if you just quickly want to unlock it. The above can be placed in a powershell.ps1 script file, then you can run it, enter your password, and drive is unlocked.

Comment: So no simple way in powershell?

Comment: This is as simple as it gets.

Comment: The batch code works in powershell as well.